# Reading the values of cells that summarize Google Finance data results via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance, getvalue

Apps Script seems to be unable to deal with a cell that uses the average formula, when the average is over Google Finance data:

Consider that column A is full of data from Google Finance. Then you type into cell B1 `=average(A1:A100)`. Lets assume the average is 5 and as such cell, B1 shows 5. Great, except that using the following script will fail:

`var AveResult = spreadsheet.getRange('B1').getValue();`
----> The log show a #DIV/0! error

On the other hand, if you overwrite the formula in B1 and simply type in a `5`, then it works perfectly:

`var AveResult = spreadsheet.getRange('B1').getValue();`
----> The log shows 5

Is there any way to get around this problem, to use scripts with summaries of Google Finance data?

Thank you.

Comment: :( Numbers.. simple numbers. Anyway, whatever it is in there, the average formula is returning the average no problem. It's disappointing that the script can't handle the cell's output.

Comment: Yes, it's a derivative of it.

Comment: It seems you're right to some extent. Using formulas based on =GoogleFinance() data works fine. But setting a variable in scripts that refers to any data that ultimately links to the =GoogleFinance() cells doesn't work. This is a huge disappointment.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the [Official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281),

> Historical data cannot be downloaded or accessed via the Sheets API or **Apps Script.**  If you attempt to do so, you will see a #N/A error in place of the values in the corresponding cells of your spreadsheet.

The average formula is **NOT** the problem. Any attempt to take historical finance data through any formula hoops doesn't seem to be possible.

However live data doesn't seem to be restricted the same way.

Comment: With thanks to the above replies - It seems that =GoogleFinance is the problem. When using a sheet, formulas based on cells using =GoogleFinance() data works fine. But when using a script, setting a variable that refers to any cell derived from =GoogleFinance() does not work. This is a huge disappointment.