# How to get Value from a cell with formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

I have a formula in a cell (18,2) which is `=(B17-B14)*B15+B17`. So what you see if a numeric value. But when I tried to use the following script to fetch the value to a new cell, it put `#num` in the new cell. I tried other cells with formulas, when it is a simple formula, (b+c) for example, the `getValue()` works. But not this one. Why? Thank you for your help in advance!

```
function myfunction1 () 
{
    var app=SpreadsheetApp;
    var ss=app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = activeSheet.getRange(18,2);
    var fstave=range.getValue();

    // retrieve value
    activeSheet.getRange(8,8).setValue(fstave);
    Logger.log("Value: " + fstave);
}
```

Comment: What are the values / formulas used by B14, B15 and B17?

Comment: they are all formulas though: b14:   =AVERAGE(OFFSET(F2,COUNT(F:F)-B13,0,B13)) b15:  =2/(B13+1)   b17 is a cell address: =ADDRESS(count(F:F)-B13,6)

Comment: And what is the underlying data? Raw numbers? imports? Google Finance output?

Comment: Thank you tehhowch. The data in F is googlefinance output. could be considered  raw numbers.

Comment: No, by design you cannot use programming to access historical Google Finance data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656540/reading-the-values-of-cells-that-summarize-google-finance-data-results-via-apps

Comment: I get data via formula and go as far as I can using formula to get the 1st EMA in cell (18,20). Now I want to move the value to next to the value on F column so I can start another set of formula to get moving average. That is what I thought I may be able to do. But the code won't bring the value over.

Comment: I am going to study a bit more and then comeback to you for help. Thank you for the link!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading the values of cells that summarize Google Finance data results via Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656540/reading-the-values-of-cells-that-summarize-google-finance-data-results-via-apps)

Answer (score 0):

You shold be able to use getDisplayValue() for the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you for response. I did try it after searching google and this forum. However, it doesn't work. what setValue did was a #VALUE!, instead of #NUM. Any ideas? Thanks again!